# How to play sound in Vaadin 14?

Tags: java, vaadin, html5-audio, vaadin14

I want to play sound (.wav, as byte[]) in one of my apps I develop using `Vaadin 14`. Unfortunately I did not find a component for this use case.

Vaadin 8 offered `Audio` (https://vaadin.com/api/framework/8.5.2/com/vaadin/ui/Audio.html) but it is not available in Vaadin 14.

I think there is a solution by simply using `HTML <audio>` and import this.

```
<body>
  <audio src="test.wav" controls autoplay loop>
    </audio>
</body>
```

Is there also a "Vaadin 14"-solution for this?

Comment: As noticed in migration guide here : https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/migration/5-components.html, it's exactly the solution- using a `<audio>` native element. So you are doing it right :)

Comment: You could create your own `Audio` component using the `<audio>` html code as template. I'm not writing an answer as I have never done that myself and could not help further than pointing in the right direction. There is quite some [documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/polymer-templates/tutorial-template-basic.html) about it.

Comment: I stand corrected - anasmis approach (see his answer) is much better and easier for this "simple" html element. Do not follow my suggestion of creating a polymer template. You would need to do this only for more complex things.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As we mentioned in comments, there is no out-of-the-box component in V14, but it's quite easy to make an own one as described here : [Creating a Simple Component Using the Element API](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/creating-components/tutorial-component-basic.html) :)

So I've checked it briefly and this seems to work:

`AudioPlayer.java`

```java
import com.vaadin.flow.component.Component;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.Tag;

@Tag("audio")
public class AudioPlayer  extends Component {

    public AudioPlayer(){
        getElement().setAttribute("controls",true);

    }

    public  void setSource(String path){
        getElement().setProperty("src",path);
    }
}
```

Using:

```java
AudioPlayer player=new AudioPlayer();
player.setSource("https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/file_example_WAV_1MG.wav");
add(player);
```

I don't have any music file locally, so taken some random one from internet and passed as a source. That's, of course, not a bulletproof solution, just a proof of concept : )

Comment: Thank you so much for this great answer! It works like a charm. I am still pretty new to Vaadin and your example did so much more than simply solving my issue. Now that I see your example the @Tag makes so much sense...

Comment: Your solution works perfectly on desktop browser but does not work on mobile - any idea why?

Comment: Not sure yet. What phone have you tested? This might be related ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34837930/audio-tag-autoplay-not-working-in-mobile
Or how exactly it doesn't work? Doesn't play an audio?

Comment: I tested it on iOS (Firefox, Safari and Chrome). Instead of the play button there is shown 'error'. I tried to disable the 'autoplay' but it does not fix the issue.

Comment: Let me try on my phone also

Comment: I have quite an old version 10.3.1 of ios, but it works here on my phone(Chrome and Safari). What are you using a as source?

Comment: I am streaming my audio file (see the comment down below).

Comment: Could you try to  replace with an url from my example in test purposes. Does it work in this case?

Comment: The audio works if I use your audio file from the comment so the issue seems to be with the StreamResource.

Comment: Alright :/ Similar issues seem to be reported through years. Could you try , first, setting `MIME` type as discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26406923/vaadin-audio-element-doesnt-work-when-i-use-it-to-play-m4a-sound-files-vaadin/26408896?

Comment: Hehe I found a fix! You have to set the ContentType for the stream to make it work. I will add it to my comment below. Thank you so much for your help again!

Comment: Cool!:)  No problem, great you've found a proper fix!

Answer (score 5):

I want to add a short addition to [anasmi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6547113/anasmi)'s great answer for those who may use streams.

Anasmi's AudioPlayer.java:

```
public void setSource(final AbstractStreamResource resource) {
    getElement().setAttribute("src", resource);
}
```

To make it work you have to set the content type for the stream:

```
var stream = new StreamResource("foo", () -> {
                        byte[] data = getBytesFromFileMP3(soundfile);
                        return new ByteArrayInputStream(data); })
                        .setContentType("audio/mpeg"); // For MP3
```

Answer (score 3):

I would make a little addition to Anasmi's answer too - if you want to play the sound on purpose (like when clicked on a button or something like that), you can add method play in this way:

```
public void play() {
    getElement().callJsFunction("play");
}
```

Hope it helps someone.